# Why my httpcontext.cache works in localhost but not production?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching, webserver

I am using HttpContext.Cache to cache my data but it only works in my localhost.

In production, the cache doesn't works, my method always go to my database retrive the data, instead catch them from the cache. I use just one instance of Sql Server and one web server.

My code is like this

```
 protected void LoadMenuSistem()
        {
            string menu = ""; 
            if (Cache["menuSistem"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write(Cache["menuSistem"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                  // Retrive data from  database and populate the string menu
            }

            Cache["menuSistem"] = menu;
}
```

Comment: FYI, your code above is susceptible to a race condition on the cache data. See http://scottcate.mykb.com/Article_5CB26.aspx

Comment: Very good article, I can implement this Cache pattern, but I has to discover why in localhost everything works fine but in the Web Server I miss the Cache.

Comment: your code invalidates the cache *after every cache hit* by assigning an empty `menu` to `Cache["menuSistem"]`...

Comment: but...just on web server ? why this doesn't occurs in localhost ?

Comment: the cache uses AFAIK some thread to scavenge old/unused entries and/or react to situations where memory is low etc. - this means as long as you don't make specific settings for the cache this is rather timing- and memory-related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the CPU Usage and RAM size in your production server. incase of low memory in the server  cached items to be removed to free memory based on the priority set. This process is known as scavenging.